# Kotlin Flow not collected anymore after working initially

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Basically I want to make a network request when initiated by the user, collect the Flow returned by the repository and run some code depending on the result. My current setup looks like this:

**Viewmodel**

```
private val _requestResult = MutableSharedFlow<Result<Data>>()
val requestResult = _requestResult.filterNotNull().shareIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileViewSubscribed,
    replay = 0
)

fun makeRequest() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.makeRequest().collect { _requestResult.emit(it) }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
buttonLayout.listener = object : BottomButtonLayout.Listener {
    override fun onButtonClick() {       
        viewModel.makeRequest()
    }
}

lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
    viewModel.requestResult.collect { result ->
        when (result) {
            Result.Loading -> {
                doStuff()
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                doDifferentStuff(result.data)
            }
            is Result.Failure -> {
                handleError()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time the request is made everything seems to work. But starting with the second time the collect block in the fragment does not run anymore. The request is still made, the repository returns the flow as expected, the collect block in the viewmodel runs and emit() also seems to be executed successfully.

So what could be the problem here? Something about the coroutine scopes? Admittedly I lack any sort of deeper understanding of the matter at hand.
Also is there a more efficient way of accomplishing what I'm attempting using Kotlin Flows in general? Collecting  a flow and then emitting the same flow again seems a bit counterintuitive.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please share all your codes and specify the exact issue you faced. 1. Where exactly does the `makeRequest()` get called? 1. `But starting with the second time the collect block is not run anymore.`  Which collect block doesn't run?

Comment: Not sure about exact issue, but I suggest using `MutableStateFlow` instead of `MutableSharedFlow`

Comment: What does `repository.makeRequest()` actually return.?A Flow coming from a repository would typically be an infinite flow, in which case calling your `ViewModel.makeRequest()` will add redundant collections of the same values. Your `filterNotNull()` call is useless since you're using it on a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there are two recommended alternatives:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { 
   viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
         //your thing
    }
}
```

I rather the other alternative:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
 
   viewModel.makeReques().flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
        .collect {
            // Process the value.
        }
}
```

I like the `flowWithLifecycle` shorter syntax and less boiler plate. Be carefull thar is bloking so you cant have anything after that.

The oficial docs

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Please be aware you need the lifecycle aware library.